# how to replace string with another one by one with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this code and my question is how can I use preg_replace to replace string one by one

```
$arr = ["{A}","{B}","{C}","{A}"];
$string = "{A}{B}{C}{A}";
foreach ($arr as $item){

    $replacement = "<span class=\"c\">{$item}</span>";
    $new_String = preg_replace("/$item/",$replacement ,$string);

}
```

the result is this :

```
<span class="c">
    <span class="c">{A}</span>
</span>

<span class="c">{B}</span>

<span class="c">{C}</span>

<span class="c">
    <span class="c">{A}</span>
</span>
```

Because I have 2 {A} in my string preg_replace make 2 span for both of the {A} . 
how to fix this ?

Comment: Your code has a few mistakes - the inner quotes in `"<span class="c">{chord}</span>"` need to be escaped, `new_String` doesn't have a `$` and probably should be `$string`

Comment: yes you are right but I just use simple example for my problem . Edited

Comment: With the corrections - your example works and gives `<span class="c">{chord}</span><span class="c">{chord}</span><span class="c">{chord}</span><span class="c">{chord}</span>`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, ermmm - don't tell anyone as it's a trade secret - but I ran the code and printed out the result.

Comment: @NigelRen yes you are right I edit post again . thanks

Comment: Still think `$new_String` should be `$string` otherwise the result is always the result of the last replacement and not accumulative.

Comment: You `$arr` variable contains two `{A}` elements - shouldn't that be unique?

Comment: Use `$arr = array_unique($arr);` and then do what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Casimir's suggested snippets, you can also use this one:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mNjbu))

```
$arr   = ["{A}", "{B}", "{C}", "{A}"];
$start = '<span class="c">';
$end   = '</span>';
$string = "{A}{B}{C}{A}";

foreach (array_unique($arr) as $item) {
    $string = str_replace($item, $start . $item . $end, $string);
}

echo $string;
```

It alters how you define the replacement, but avoids regex.

As a more robust, solution (if your project requires it), using `strtr()` is ideal for multiple replacements on the same string because it avoid replacing a replacement.  As you can see in Casimir's answer, there's a bit of preparation required.

Here's a language-construct version of the Casimir's technique: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/a4SiM))

```
$arr   = ["{A}", "{B}", "{C}", "{A}"];

foreach (array_unique($arr) as $item) {
    $translator[$item] = '<span class="c">' . $item . '</span>';
}

var_export($translator);
echo "\n\n---\n\n";

$string = "{A}{B}{C}{A}";

echo strtr($string, $translator);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '{A}' => '<span class="c">{A}</span>',
  '{B}' => '<span class="c">{B}</span>',
  '{C}' => '<span class="c">{C}</span>',
)

---

<span class="c">{A}</span><span class="c">{B}</span><span class="c">{C}</span><span class="c">{A}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `preg_replace` a wrong way: the main interest of this function is to take a regex pattern as parameter, and a pattern isn't to describe a fixed string but can describe several kind of strings (and this way you don't have to use a `foreach` loop since you can replace the whole string in 1 pass), example:

```
$result = preg_replace('/{[A-G]}/', '<span class="c">$0</span>', $string);
```

---

Other way, since you want to replace only fixed strings, you can use `strtr` that also does the job in one pass:

```
$arr = ["{A}","{B}","{C}"];
$rep = array_map(function($i) { return '<span class="c">' . $i . '</span>'; }, $arr);
$trans = array_combine($arr, $rep);

$result = strtr($string, $trans);
```

Comment: OP isn't upping, so I am.  Good answer.